# Looping through JSON with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to loop through JSON values with SwiftyJSON in order to show them in a UIAlertController.

In my API call using Alamofire I am returning some JSON data using

```
if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {

 let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
 let token = json["api_token"].string

 response(token: token, errorVal: json)

} else {
  return
}
```

Then in my VC I use that data with:

```
if let errorVal = errorVal {

var errorMessages = ""

for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in errorVal {

   errorMessages = errorMessages + String(subJson) + "\n"
 }

}
```

*errorVal* is returning:

```
{
  "email" : [
    "The email field is required."
  ],
  "password" : [
    "The password field is required."
  ]
}
```

and *errorMessages*

```
[
"The email field is required."
]
[
"The password field is required."
]
```

But I want *errorMessages* to display this instead:

```
The email field is required
The password field is required
```

How can I loop through the JSON and only get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since subJson is an array of strings, get the first one.

```
if let errorVal = errorVal {
    var errorMessages = ""

    for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in errorVal {
        // Looks like subJson is an array, so grab the 1st element
        let s = subJson[0].string
        errorMessages = errorMessages + s + "\n"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
var newMessage = String(subJson).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    newMessage = newMessage.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    errorMessages = errorMessages + newMessage + "\n"
```